# WooCommerce catalog images sizing and overlaping issues

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, size

Im having problems with the catalog images on my wordpress site.

The images are all in different aspect ratio, some are 1:1 others are 1:2. WooCommerce only lets me define thumbnail width, resulting in some images being twice as high as others.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR2cc.jpg)

I tried to fix this using this code i found:

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a .et_shop_image img {
 width: auto;
 margin: 0 auto !important;
 display: block;
 max-width: 180px;
 max-height: 180px;
}
```

This fixes the height issue, and it looks good on larger displays. But on smaller screens the images gets squished together and overlap eachother.

Anyone had same issues? Whats the best way to fix this? **I want square thumbnails with the image fitted inside (like using background-size: contain).**

Thankful for all help i can get here.
Cheers.

Comment: Second screenshot of images overlapping eachother after implementing the code snippet above: https://imgur.com/a/5Nma26m

Comment: Im using Wordpress 4.9.5 with the Divi theme and WooCommerce 3.3.5 if it matters.